# Read pdf as ArrayBuffer to store it in json file with detailed information

Tags: javascript

I want to build a wrapper around a pdf document to store more information. I tried the `FileReader` with `reader.readAsBinaryString()` but this broke the pdf file (some parts like images were missing).

So I tried `reader.readAsArrayBuffer()` which seems to get the content without any damage. But I don't know to to convert the ArrayBuffer to a string so I can write it's value into a json file to export it.
When I use `btoa(new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(e.target.result))`

I get an **error** : `The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.`

Comment: UTF-8 has very specific limitations on what sequences of bytes can appear in a string, it's not suitable for representing arbitrary binary data. Try a different encoding, like `latin2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like a terrible idea in general, but anyway, might help someone else...

The easiest and most reliable way to encode a binary file to a string is to encode it as [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

The FileReader API has a [`readAsDataURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) method, which will return a [data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) composed of both an URI header and the base64 binary data.
So all you need if you want only the data as string, is to grab whatever comes after "base64," in the returned dataURI.

```js
inp.onchange = e => {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = e => {
    var myObj = {
      name: inp.files[0].name,
      data: reader.result.split('base64,')[1]
    };
    console.log(JSON.stringify(myObj));
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(inp.files[0]);
};
```

```html
<input type="file" id="inp">
```

Now, I can't advice to store a whole pdf file, moreover which contains images in a JSON file. Encoded as base64 the binary data will grow by 34% (IIRC). So you might want to consider saving both the meta-data and the original pdf file in a single binary compressed file (e.g zip).

Comment: I need to create a wrapper so I can export it to another app with some information without touching the original file. But the Idea with the zip file sounds also good.